# Odbc driver returned a decimal that is out of range, Power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, odbc, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to import data from mongodb using the atlas sql connector in power bi. i have downloaded the atlas odbc driver too. Most data are retrieved properly but the decimal128 fields throw an error quoting " The odbc driver returned a decimal that is out of range or cannot be understood.

Is there any solution to this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxRmp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YJHI.png)

I tried transforming the values into text and decimal, but no luck. But when I change the type of data from decimal128 to double, it works perfectly.